# Convert Excel to SQL and then to JSON to opmitise data response sent to the client in NodeJS

Tags: node.js, json, excel, api, heroku

I have an application where we upload an Excel file with data using this method:

```
// Upload and replace excel file for a new version of the excel file
app.post('/data', function (req, res) {
  const upload = multer({ storage }).single('document');
  fs.unlink(path2, (err) => {
    if (err) {
      console.error(err)
      return
    }
    upload(req, res, function (err) {
      if (err) {
        return res.end("error lors de upload")
      }
      res.redirect('/')
    })
  })
});
```

Then there is another method that converts the excel into JSON and sends the data to the client:

```
// Converts Excel to JSON and send to client
app.get('/json2', (req, res) => {
  node_xj({
    input: "uploads/data.xlsx",
    output: "output.json"
  }, function (err, result) {
    if (err) {
      console.error(err);
    } else {
      const interval = setInterval(() => {
        console.log('test')
      }, 3600 * 24 * 365)
      res.send(result);
      console.log("results send ok");
    }
  });
})
```

However, this process is slow because at every request of data from the client, the server has to convert excel into JSON and send the data, so sometimes the client does not get the data.

I would like to know if it is possible to optimise this with a script by putting the Excel data into SQL and then the json2 route converts SQL to JSON and sends to the client.

My nodejs application is deployed in Heroku right now.

Do you know how to do this? Could you please give some advice?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why would adding another transformation speed this up? it'll be slower. If the bottleneck is the `node_xj` part, you need to optimise that. How many rows are in the excel, is the JSON output flat, and how long does it currently take to run? How does " the client does not get the data" - is there a timeout? Are they closing their browser?

Comment: The client is an IONIC Angular app, Android and IOS, and when the client requests the api to fetch the data the route transforms the excel file into json and send the JSON back. I saw in postman that this request is on average 5s long. And as it is so slow, sometimes there are errors and the does not get the data. 

I thought that if before that when I upload the excel file via POST request, I can store the excel data into a database, then the client could request the database to get the data and that would be faster than requesting and converting an excel file.

Comment: I am also exploring the possibility of a POST request to upload the excel file > Convert to excel and store the data into a JSON file in the project > the GET request from the client sends this JSON file directly... but so far I couldn't do it